# Matching a raster projection to simple features spatial layer using R

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, sf, raster-conversion

I have two dataframes in R. One, df_points, has spatial information saved as points. The other, df_raster, is a raster file. I want to extract information from the raster to the points using:

```
rasValue = extract(df_raster, df_points)
```

However, they use different projections:

```
crs(df_raster)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=lcc +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +lat_1=34.3333333333333 +lat_2=36.1666666666667 +x_0=609601.22
+y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
crs(df_points)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=lcc +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +lat_1=36.1666666666667 +lat_2=34.3333333333333
+x_0=609601.219202438 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=us-ft +no_defs
```

I want to reproject the raster data to match the df_points data. I thought I could use the sf package with st_transform, which has worked when I was just using simple features spatial data, however, this spits out an error and doesn't seem to work with rasters.

```
df_raster<- st_transform(
  df_raster,
  crs=st_crs(df_points)
)

Error in UseMethod("st_transform") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_transform' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"
```

How else can I do this?

Comment: Way mor efficient to reproject your points using `sf::st_transform`. You can pull the correct CRS from the raster using`sf::st_crs(raster::crs(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I have two dataframes in R. One, df_points, has spatial information saved as points. The other, df_raster, is a raster file"

Firstly, `df_raster` is not a data frame. Its also not a raster file. Its an object of class "RasterLayer" (and "Raster" and "BasicRaster") from the `raster` package. (I'm getting this from the error message you show, but its always a good idea here to show some output from your data, maybe the result of `summary` on your data or some maps.)

This means the functions to reproject it are going to be in the `raster` package. A little search should find `projectRaster` and the help page shows:

```
pr1 <- projectRaster(r, crs=newproj)
```

That said, as noted in comments, its nearly always better to project point, polygons, and lines data (vector data) to coordinate systems of rasters, since transforming rasters involves a non-reversible transformation with some information loss. The only time you should have to transform a raster is when you have two rasters with different coordinate systems and you need to match them up for further processing.